# my users details is not is not rendering users list when i type in search

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, console, warnings, mern

there is one more error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'handleShow' of 'object null' as it is null.
output when i consoled log is
pr
SearchModal.js:35 {username: "pr"}
SearchModal.js:38 [{…}]0: {*id: "602df77cea2b563d7ceda4ac", username: "pratik", email: "pratik@gmail.com"}length: 1__proto*_: Array(0)
also it is not searching when i type p its giving searc:'' and when i add prat then search : 'pra' only
Also it is not rendering username just check userdetails.map it is console logging the details but not rendering on page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SearchUser } from '../services/SearchService';
import {Modal} from 'react-bootstrap';

class SearchModal extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        show: false,
        search: '',
        userdetails:[]
    }

    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    this.onTextboxChangeSearch = this.onTextboxChangeSearch.bind(this);
}
handleShow() {
    this.setState({ show: true })
}
handleClose(){
    this.setState({ show: false })
}

async onTextboxChangeSearch(event) {

  this.setState({
      search: event.target.value
  });
  let {search,userdetails} = this.state;
  console.log(search)


  const data = {username:search};
  console.log(data)
  let SearchStatus = await SearchUser(data);
  userdetails=SearchStatus.user
  console.log(userdetails);
}

render() {
    let {search,userdetails}= this.state;

    return (
       <div>
          <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
             <Modal.Header closeButton>
               <Modal.Title>
                 <input 
                  type="text" 
                  placeholder="Search.."
                  value={search}
                  onChange={this.onTextboxChangeSearch}
                 ></input>
               </Modal.Title>
             </Modal.Header>
             <Modal.Body>
               <h3>Users</h3>
               <div>
               <ul>
                {userdetails.map(element => {
                  <li>{element.username}</li>
                })}
              </ul>
               </div>
             </Modal.Body>
          </Modal>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
export default SearchModal;
```

Dashboard

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link,Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserService from "../services/userservice";
import SearchModal from './SearchModal'

export default class Dashboard extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
            currentUser: UserService.getCurrentUser(),
            isLoading:false,
        };

        this.logOut = this.logOut.bind(this);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);

    }

    logOut() {
        UserService.logout()
    }

    SearchModalRef = ({handleShow}) => {
        this.showModal = handleShow;
    }
    
    onClick = () => {
        this.showModal();
    }
     

    render(){
        const { currentUser ,isLoading } = this.state;
        console.log(currentUser)

        if (isLoading) {
            return (<div><p>Loading...</p></div>);
        }

        if(!currentUser){
            return(
                <div>
                    <Redirect  to='/login' />
                </div>
            )
        }
        else{
            return(
                <div>
                    <header>
                        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
                        {' '}
                        <div>
                            <Link to={`/dashboard/profile/:${currentUser.user._id}`}>Profile</Link>
                        </div>
                        {' '}
                        <div>
                            <Link to="/login" onClick={this.logOut}>LogOut</Link>
                        </div>
                        {' '}
                        
                        <SearchModal  ref={this.SearchModalRef} ></SearchModal>
                        <button type="button" onClick={this.onClick}>
                        Search
                        </button>
                    </header>
                    <div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you attempt to destructure `handleShow` from anything, let alone where it's even used or referenced. About your other issue, react state updates are asynchronous, so you can't enqueue a state update and expect to use the euqueued state value later in the same function. In other words, this is why the `search` value is a render cycle behind in `onTextboxChangeSearch`.

Comment: so for that what can i do

Comment: Use `event.target.value` instead of search in the body of `onTextboxChangeSearch`, or leave the state update and refactor the search logic into its own function that is invoked in the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method with the updated `search` state value.

Comment: sry i didnt  get what you are asing me to do could you code it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

> it is not searching when i type p its giving searc:'' and when i add
> prat then search : 'pra' only

React state updates are asynchronous and batch processed between render cycles. This means when you enqueue a state update it won't be available until the next render cycle. Any further references to state in the same function will be the state value from the current render cycle.

```
async onTextboxChangeSearch(event) {
  this.setState({
    search: event.target.value // <-- next state
  });
  let {search,userdetails} = this.state; // <-- still current state!
  console.log(search)

  const data = {username:search};
  console.log(data)
  let SearchStatus = await SearchUser(data);
  userdetails=SearchStatus.user
  console.log(userdetails);
}
```

## Solution

I suggest factoring out the search logic into its own function to be called by the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle methods when state updates.

```
onTextboxChangeSearch(event) {
  const { value } = event.target;
  this.setState({
    search: value // <-- (1) update state
  });
}


searchForUser = async () => { // <-- (3) refactored search function
  const { search, userdetails } = this.state;
  const data = { username: search };

  const { user } = await SearchUser(data);
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    userdetails: [...prevState.userdetails, user], // append user
  }));
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.search !== this.state.search) {
    this.searchForUser(); // <-- (2) search state updated, do search for user
  }
}
```

Comment: it  is giving this error Line 43:5:  'searchForUser' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @PratikZinjurde it is an arrow function, you shouldn't need to do any binding in a constructor. I actually just forgot to call it as `this. searchForUser`, so a typo on my part. I haven't used class-based components for at least a year, but an IDE would've caught that easily. Answer is updated. Sorry for trouble/confusion.

Comment: exactly i was thinking of that i removed binding too thanks @DrewReese appreciate

Comment: this is not working correctly now in console log data and userdetails are                            {username: "a"}
SearchModal.js:41 
[]
SearchModal.js:37 
{username: "ab"}
SearchModal.js:41 
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {_id: "602d50fb11d7500428c270b8", username: "abc", email: "abc@gmail.com"}
1: {_id: "602df77cea2b563d7ceda4ac", username: "pratik", email: "pratik@gmail.com"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: also why it is not rendering list  <ul>
                {userdetails.map(element => {
                  <li>{element.username}</li>
                })}
              </ul>

Comment: i didnt added return statement next to map line now after adding it is working